Tensioning a spooled cable to prevent bunching cable
I am looking for economical ways to prevent the bunching of spooled cable on a hoist/winch. I have come across commercially available winch cable tensioners which essentially work by applying a rotational force to a roller which then presses against the spooled cable preventing the bunching. As in this drawing

I have included links to two videos to show how these methods work and attached images of one unit, and bunching in cable.
In my use case I utilize steel cable and a hoist (presumably designed or tested for force that is upwards and downwards).
Questions:

Would this method as shown in two videos below work the same if used together with a hoist where the force is upwards/downwards rather than horizontal as in the winch shown in videos.
Is the mechanism used with plate tensioners similar when downspooling (releasing cable from spool) as it is when upspooling (bringing cable back into the spool).
Are there other methods in general that are more efficient or economical that can be applied when using a hoist?

Plate Tensioner image

Bunching

Videos
Video One
Video Two

Most winch designs that include spooling tensioners are after a low-cost solution...

on vehicle-mounted winches, you unspool the cable, attach it to a tree with a strop, and then winch the vehicle up to the tree. Zero cost. Oh, Warn actually has a video on it - https://www.google.com/search?q=winch+cable+bunching&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS1086US1087&oq=winch+cable+bunching&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigAdIBCTEyMTE2ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:d58690b7,vid:oZZ5GLcNZHw,st:0

The next cheapest system is one that won't wind the drum if it cable is slack. These are quite common as well. https://www.harken.com/en/shop/3t-electric-captives/3t-24v-electric-captive-reel-winch-420-mm-length-18-mm-line-o-right-hand/
